# Webscraping from yellowbook

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm fairly good at programming python but of course i want to write cleaner code.

This is a simple script that scrapes leads off yellowbook.

I want to utilize list comprehensions but im comfortable with using for loops, however i can see how it can be repetitive.

Any ways i can make this cleaner ?

```
service_name = input("Input Industry: ")
city = input("Input The City: ")

class Item(scrapy.Item):
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    phone_number = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.yellowbook.com/s/" + service_name + "/" + city 
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_business_names = []
        self.seen_websites = []


    def parse(self, response):
        for business in response.css('div.listing-info'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('div.info.l h2 a::text').extract()
            item['website'] = business.css('a.s_website::attr(href)').extract()
            for x in item['business_name'] and item['website']:
                #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
                if (x not in self.seen_business_names and x not in self.seen_websites):
                    if item['business_name']:
                        if item['website']:
                            item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phone-number::text').extract_first()
                            yield item
                            self.seen_business_names.append(x)




        # next_page = response.css('div.pagination a::attr(href)').extract()
        for href in response.css('ul.page-nav.r li a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
```

Comment: `for x in item['business_name'] and item['website']:` is this really doing what you expect it to? I mean, maybe you really wanted to write `if bool(item['business_name']) and bool(item['website']): for x in item['website']:` in a shorter way, but the rest of the code looks more like you wanted to write `for x in item['business_name'] + item['website']:`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: a general observation - simple nested `if` statements are equivalent to a single `if` with statements joined by `and`.

So:

```
if a:
    if b:
        if c:
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if a and b and c:
```

Second: You have an `if` test to see if `business_name` and `website` exist - but you do a lot of other things before this test. You can move this higher up so you 'escape' that code faster if you do something like:

```
item['business_name'] = business.css('div.info.l h2 a::text').extract()
item['website'] = business.css('a.s_website::attr(href)').extract()
if item['business_name'] and item['website']:
    for x in item['business_name'] and item['website']:
        #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
        if (x not in self.seen_business_names and x not in self.seen_websites):
            item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phone-number::text').extract_first()
            self.seen_business_names.append(x)
            yield item
```

(I've put the `append` before the `yield` as this seems slightly clearer to me).

Third - I don't think you mean `for x in item['business_name'] and item['website']:`

Rather can do either of:

```
for x in item['business_name'] + item['website']:
```

Or:

```
from itertools import chain
for x in chain(item['business_name'], item['website']):
```